# Swift 3 - Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT Unrecognised selector sent to Instance

Tags: swift, xcode

could any please help me solve this problem? I have been at it trying to fix the issue for a few hours but nothing has worked so far. Everytime I click a button it immediately leads to the error Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT.

This is the code (Note: It is still a work in Progress):

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var Sec1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Sec2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Sec3: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Sec4: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Sec5: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Sec6: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Sec7: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Sec8: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Sec9: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
var x = 2
   // if (x%2 == 0) {
    @IBAction func ButtonPressed(Button1: UIButton) {
   Sec1.text = "X"
    }    
}
```

This is the Error:

```
**2017-02-23 07:58:14.194 Tic Tac Toe IS[46707:2457511] -[Tic_Tac_Toe_IS.ViewController ButtonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb8a8d04ee0
2017-02-23 07:58:14.202 Tic Tac Toe IS[46707:2457511] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Tic_Tac_Toe_IS.ViewController ButtonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb8a8d04ee0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bebfd4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001092be21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bf2ff04 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010be45005 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010be44b88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010978f8bc -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000109915c38 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000109915f51 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000109914e4d -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 668
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001097fd545 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2747
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001097fec33 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001097ab9ab -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000109f9872d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000109f91463 __handleEventQueue + 4879
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010be64761 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010be4998c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010be48e76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010be48884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010ddf9a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010978dc68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    20  Tic Tac Toe IS                      0x0000000108cdb7af main + 111
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010ce6f68d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)**
```

Comment: Did you use Interface builder to set up your `IBAction` Method ?

Comment: Remove action from storyboard & remove code & then readd button action `@IBAction func ButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {}`

Comment: I dragged the button on the storyboard to the View Controller

Comment: Mukesh, I am confused by what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the connection between your @IBAction func ButtonPressed() with storyboard? You can check it from the "Connection inspector" on the storyboard.

Comment: This is what is on my screen when I go onto the Connection Inspector (I am still a beginner)  https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pRip.png

Comment: I think the problem might be that you were miss connecting one of your Buttons to the IBAction. Could you check once again?

Comment: How do I check for that? I only connected one button to the IBAction, is there a way to connect all of them?

Comment: If you want to connect all you do the same as you did for first connected button. But is that what you want? (connect all buttons to one IBAction?)

Comment: I want to be able to check whether button x is clicked or not (where all the button variables are stored as an array) and if button x is clicked than label x will print "X"

Comment: Okay. So i think the best solution would be using UIButton tag to accomplish what you want. The way you do it is that you can set the tag value of each button and then using switch statement in your IBAction to display what you want upon selected button.